# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module inertiajs laravel vitejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, vite, inertiajs

I am using Inertiajs, Laravel and Vuejs. with vitejs. When running node bootstrap/ssr/ssr.mjs everything gets compiled.. but when opening withe webapp I get below errors.  when I go with their recommended ways.. the app dosent work.

C:\xampp\htdocs\project\node_modules\vue-currency-input\dist\index.esm.js:6
import { ref, getCurrentInstance, isVue3, computed, watch, onUnmounted } from 'vue-demi';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1088:15)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1123:27)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:169:29)
at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)
at async Promise.all (index 0)
at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:530:24)
C:\xampp\htdocs\project\node_modules\vue-currency-input\dist\index.esm.js:6
import { ref, getCurrentInstance, isVue3, computed, watch, onUnmounted } from 'vue-demi';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:360:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1088:15)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1123:27)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:169:29)
at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)
at async Promise.all (index 0)
at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:530:24)

when i use type: module

i get this error

> vite build && vite build --ssr

failed to load config from C:\xampp\htdocs\project\vite.config.ts
error during build:
TypeError: laravel is not a function
at file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/project/vite.config.ts.timestamp-1667048487178.mjs:7:5
at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)
at async Promise.all (index 0)
at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:530:24)
at async loadConfigFromBundledFile (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/project/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-0ebb5606.js:63514:21)
at async loadConfigFromFile (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/project/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-0ebb5606.js:63409:28)
at async resolveConfig (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/project/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-0ebb5606.js:63026:28)
at async doBuild (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/project/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-0ebb5606.js:45673:20)
at async build (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/project/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-0ebb5606.js:45662:16)
at async CAC. (file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/project/node_modules/vite/dist/node/cli.js:748:9)